# How to do something else except printing in alarm Manager [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter

I just ended up configuring the alarm manager. I came to know that we can only use static top level methods in the alarm_manager.If I wish to open my app after a specific period of time how do I do it??

The plugin 
https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

Comment: alarm manager? in flutter? it does not have any alarm manager or you use some extra package you did not mention about...

Comment: Assuming you are using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager. Yes the alarm manager runs even when the app is closed

Comment: Yes I meant that plugin

Comment: Can we do smthing other than printing text as it needs a static or top level methods. Like showing dialog or smthing else than printing

Comment: who said it has to be a static or top level method?

Comment: The vs code says so

Comment: Also when I print the future returned by alarm manager it prints true if it's outside  the class extending stateless widget else it returns false if I try to use it within the same class

Comment: android studio does not say so

Comment: Ok I'll try Android studio                thanks fr answering

Comment: It says the same in Android studio too you can Ctrl+click on the alarm manager and read the comments. Can you give me an working example showing a dialog with alarm manager

Comment: By static and top level methods I mean to say about the callback in        :-               Alarm manager.one shot(delay,id,callback)

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu can we do other tasks other than printing text in console with alarm_manager